# Need help setup mount seaweedfs with autofs or systemd automount

Tags: autofs, automount

I want to mount on demand using autofs or systemd automount. But I can't get neither of it to work.

With autofs. I have this file

cat /etc/auto.weed

```
/mnt/data -fstype=weed,allow_other,rw,filer=10.104.0.5,filer.path=/data
```

I try to change -fstype=weed to -fstype=fuse but still not work. I don't know how to get the right config

With systemd automount. I have this config in fstab

```
fuse /mnt/data weed noauto,x-systemd.automount,_netdev,filer=10.104.0.5:8888,filer.path=/data 0 0
```

When I run systemctl start mnt-data.automount It return error "No such device" when I try to access /mnt/data. But I run mount and it work normal

If someone how to make it work. Please give some pointer Thank you

Answer (score 0):

ln -s /sbin/weed /sbin/mount.weed

fuse /data fuse.weed defaults,_netdev,x-systemd.automount,filer='xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8888,xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8888,xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8888',filer.path=/ 0 0